# Running java program from terminal

Tags: java, linux, swing, terminal, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a java program to run on the raspberry pi and I can't get it to run using terminal.

It consists of two classes both of which are located at:

```
/home/pi/JBerries/Access control/bin/access/control
```

Also note it is a GUI program made using swing.

This is the command I'm using to try and run it currently:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/JBerries/Access control $ java -classpath .bin.access.control.accessControlUI
```

And this is what it spits out:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-client       to select the "client" VM
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more     details.
```

Is this a sign that my program is ready to run and I just need to include some sort of launch option? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `.bin.` looks wrong...

Comment: What is the name of your class (including package)? Do you want `java -classpath "$CLASSPATH:./bin" access.control.accessControlUI` or `java -classpath . bin.access.control.accessControlUI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
java -classpath . bin.access.control.accessControlUI
```

Notice the "space" between . and bin