# Unable to run program Exception in thread "main" NoClassDefFoundError: (wrong name: access/control/accessControlUI)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, noclassdeffounderror

This question is the evolution of a previous question which was answered (I wasn't sure if it was convention to start a new question or continue from the previous one at this point - please let me know):
[Running java program from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104940/running-java-program-from-terminal/21105191#21105191)

I'm struggling to get my java program to run from terminal. I'm launch it it from the following location:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/JBerries/Access control $
```

Using this command:

```
java -classpath . bin/access/control/accessControlUI
```

It's a swing GUI program and main is located in accessControlUI and it also requires the door class, here's an image so yo can see the files:

[image: files]

Here's what I get when I execute the stated command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      bin/access/control/accessControlUI (wrong name: access/control/accessControlUI)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I found many similar questions but I struggled to draw anything useful from them and most were labeled as 'too local'.

Comment: cd to `bin` then type `java -classpath . access.control.accessControlUI`

Comment: `accessControlUI`  Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: @twj I get a similar error when I try to run from bin:    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: access/control/accessControlUI$6`

@AndrewThompson Will the naming convention stuff make a difference in this situation? - ether way I'll try and brush up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into bin directory and run the following command:

```
java -classpath . access/control/accessControlUI
```

It looks like your full class name is "access/control/accessControlUI", not "bin/access/control/accessControlUI". Check package line in accessControlUI class.

Comment: Cd-ing into the directory is not needed and may break something in the application.

Comment: Also, recommending to use `/` as the separator in Java names is not exactly instructive.

Comment: `java -cp bin access.control.accessControlUI`.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm still getting a similar error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: access/control/accessControlUI$6
`
The package line is like so:
`package access.control;`

Comment: Edit- Ignore the previous comment, looks to be a silly mistake that I made. Runs perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Many times java program compile successfully.
If it gives error while running program then please check the name of class it is case sencetive, make sure classpath.
In windows system it give error if you set classpath in environmental variable and again in running program.

Answer (score -1):

A short answer is this:

```
java -classpath bin/access/control/*:. bin/access/control/accessControlUI.class
```

Comment: You kidding? This isn't even close.